# Add onclick link event to an image with CSS

Tags: html, css, onclick

I have an image that bounces on hover but I want the user to also be able to click the image 
and be taken to another website.  What do I need to change in my code for this to work?

```
.my-custom-control { background: url('my-image.png'); 
background-size: 150px 150px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-clip: border-box;
transition: background-size 0.2s;
-webkit-transition: background-size 0.2s;
transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.05,1.2,.72,1.2);
display: inline-block; 
width: 200px; 
height: 200px; 
}
.my-custom-control:hover {
    background-size: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the HTML as well.  JavaScript too if you have any.

Comment: Wrap the `<img>` with an `<a>`, and apply the animation to that element instead of to the `<img>`.

Comment: Full code here: https://github.com/SLUGIS/CalMAPPER/blob/gh-pages/index.html

Comment: Great, now please add the relevant, *minimal*, [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) code to your question; don't expect us to go to external sites for the privilege of helping you. We like to help, but it's your job to make it as easy as possible for us to do so.

Comment: Sorry I thought you wanted the full code.  Also thought you get rep points for answering questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your image into an anchor tag...

```
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com"><img src="" class="my-custom-control"></a>
```

Comment: you have an <img tag in your code in HTML... put <a tag around it as shown in example above.

Comment: I do not have an <img tag in my HTML.  The image is a background: url in my CSS.

Comment: Just saw your code.. You can create an anchor element in your code with var imageLink = document.createElement('a'); then add your image (i believe it's a div in your case as : imageLink.appendChild().

Comment: Awesome.  Can you be more specific I am not sure where to put the var imageLink and exactly how to use it.

Comment: Here is the code you want to change in the file you shared....       var imageLink = document.createElement('a');
          imageLink.href = 'http://www.yahoo.com';
      var container = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'my-custom-control');
      imageLink.appendChild(container);

      // ... initialize other DOM elements, add listeners, etc.
      return imageLink;